# How to run a sql file in MySql Workbench without to load it?

Tags: mysql-workbench, freeze, large-data

I have a large sql file to run inside workbench.
It has 44MB.
So when I try to open it using "Open SQL Script" it freezes workbench.

I could do that through command line, but I would like to know if it's possible to run the query directly without loading in workbench.

That means, I would have only the query results in output.

Comment: 44MB is not large at all...what commands are you using to run sql file in workbench?? your reasoning for not running through the command line does not make sense...

Comment: I prefer to run in workbench because it has a great output to see warnings and error. The steps I am using to open the file in workbench is: Inside SQL Develloper, File->Open Sql Script. Point to 44Mb.sql. Then it freezes the worbench. Now I am realizing that could be a RAM memory issue.

Comment: probably is memory issue..although 44MB is not very but AT ALL...As far as output for warning and errors...Command line will show output for errors and warning you can see in mysql error log...

Comment: yes I was trying to set variables to see it in log but did.nt.  How can I set it to show in log? And where is the path? I was reading this site but not finish yet http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_warnings

Comment: Hi, yes, I've used mysql before, but never with systems variables and log. I used to do that with oracle-> plsql or sqlPlus. The company I am working now is only mysql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL Workbench has been tested with files up to 256MB. It takes a while to entirely syntax check such a file but it works. If you just want to run the file with ease use the `File -> Run Script` menu entry.

Comment: Hi Mike, what version do we have this option? Mine is 5.2.44. I am in SQL Developer module (SQL Editor). In File nemu I can not find Run Script. I do not find inside others menu options either.

Comment: The current GA version is 6.2.5 with the new 6.3 GA around the corner. Better you upgrade :-)

Comment: yes I saw that. In fact I installed the new version. I found File->Run, as you told. I also found Import data to do the same.